# Parsing data from HTML using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

from the below source code, I want to extract the InnerText "My Name" but i can single out that 1 href node and instead get the whole list of hrefs:

```
<tr class="index">
  <td class="number">1.</td>
  <td class="image">
    <a href="/image/520211/" title="My index">
    <img src=" /images/M/MV5MDE.jpg" height="74" width="54" alt="My Alt" title="My Title">
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class="name">
    <span class="name_wrapper" data-size="small" data-caller-name="search">
    </span>
    <a href="/data/520211/">My Name</a>
    <span class="year">1974</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My code so far:

```
for (var index = 0; index < htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=index']//a[@href]").Count; index++)
{
    var item = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=index']//a[@href]")[index];
    MessageBox.Show(item.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string name = "";
var node = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//tr[@class='index']//td[@class='name']//a[@href]");
if (node != null)
    name = node.InnerText;
```